# How to create default json object from json schema in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-defaults

I can not google that thing on `json.net` [api reference](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/R_Project_Documentation.htm) or anywhere.
I want to create object from json schema with default values filled in.
Basically some thing like this:

```
var JsonSchema=JsonSchema.ReadSchemaFromSomeWhere();
dynamic DefaultObject= JsonSchema.GetDefaultObject();
```

Example you might see in [json-schema-defaults](https://github.com/chute/json-schema-defaults) package.

**Example**

```
var JsonSchema=JsonSchema.ReadSchemaFromString("
{
  "title": "Album Options",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "sort": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "id"
    },
    "per_page": {
      "default": 30,
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }");

dynamic DefaultObject= JsonSchema.GetDefaultObject();

//DefaultObject dump is
{
  sort: 'id',
  per_page: 30
}
```

**UPDATE**

I want lib or api in json.net to create object with default values from any given valid json schema during runtime.

Comment: what about using 'dynamic' ?

Comment: @Marty since schema might be  arbitrary i would think that it can be create like dynamic object or i dont know Jobject instance or whatever even string, or what s your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Well a simple case might be this

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
   dynamic ob = new JsonObject();
   ob["test"] = 3;

   Assert.That(ob.test, Is.EqualTo(3));

}
```

I used the `RestSharp` library that provides a good dynamic implementation that allows indexing `["test"]`;

So then - what You're left to do is read the properties from the schema and assign values (of course this will work only for simple plain case`s, but might be a start

```
dynamic ob = new JsonObject();
foreach (var prop in JsonSchema.Properties)
{

   if (prop.Default != null)
      ob[prop.Name] = prop.Default
}
```

Comment: no , my intent is not get c# class code in order to compile, i want in runtime on any given vaiild json schema produce json object from it with default values, so im looking for lib or api in json.net, i will update my question to make it clear sorry

Comment: what would the defaults be ?  a dynamic object, with props from schema set to NULL values ?

Comment: null in case schema not specified default value  for property , if it specified default value then it should be there , check node package from reference  in question ,it does what i want in javascript

Comment: yep, working on it. seems that there is no out of the box solution. at least from NewtonSoft

Comment: thanks for looking into it!,  i checked source code of js lib - seems not too big, and might be rewritten in c# but still:)

Comment: can You post that js lib source URL ?

Comment: I added a simplified implementation, with a core solution being in RestSharp library, which allows indexing properties like ob["name"].. the rest I guess is in that js lib, or can be handled by making the function recursive (properties is a list of schema objects)

Comment: thanks for info, yes it seems good starting point ,as well as recursive it also need reference resolving

Comment: any progress with .net implementation?

Comment: @IvanYuriev we ended up implement simple recursive method on client to do this, given number of schema specification constructs  we support method pretty simple and its easy to extend if you you want to support whole schema specification